# Having trouble trying to pull data from a url into python using an API

Tags: python, api, csv, curl

I'm trying to pull data from a chart on a site in csv format. I've tried different combinations of code but can't seem to figure it out. I keep getting the following errors depending on the code I write:

TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable
TypeError: a float is required

My latest attempt looked like this:

```
import urllib   
import urllib2    
import csv    
import StringIO


url = "https://api.rjmetrics.com/0.1/chart/chartid/export"    
headers = {"X-RJM-API-Key": "myapikey"}
data = {"format=csv"}
response = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)    
re = urllib2.urlopen(response)    
spamreader = csv.reader(re, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')    
for row in spamreader:    
    print row
```

The working CURL version looks like this:

```
curl -d "format=csv" -H "X-RJM-API-Key: myapikey" https://api.rjmetrics.com/0.1/chart/chartid/export
```

but I don't know how to work with curl.

Thank you!

Comment: Bump. If you have found the answer yourself, you can still answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` should be a url encoded string, you are passing it a set -- {"format=csv"} is a set literal.  Try this:

```
data = urllib.urlencode(dict(format='csv'))
```

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of task you should use the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) package. That way you can properly set your header:

```
headers = {'X-RJM-API-Key': 'myapikey', 'content-type: text/csv'}
r = requests.get('https://api.rjmetrics.com/0.1/chart/chartid/export', headers=headers)
```

and then use the default csv reader.